# how to remove debug logs from console in jpa

Tags: java, logging, eclipselink

```
EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.79--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class NewRegistration] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.791--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class NewAuthentication] is being defaulted to: NewAuthentication.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.824--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [role] is being defaulted to: ROLE.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.827--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [address] is being defaulted to: ADDRESS.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.827--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [tokenid] is being defaulted to: TOKENID.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.828--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [gender] is being defaulted to: GENDER.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.828--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [last_name] is being defaulted to: LAST_NAME.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.829--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [sessionid] is being defaulted to: SESSIONID.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.829--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [userid] is being defaulted to: USERID.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.83--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [password] is being defaulted to: PASSWORD.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.831--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [zone] is being defaulted to: ZONE.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.832--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [integration] is being defaulted to: INTEGRATION.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.833--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [phone_number] is being defaulted to: PHONE_NUMBER.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.834--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [lang] is being defaulted to: LANG.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.834--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [first_name] is being defaulted to: FIRST_NAME.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.835--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [email] is being defaulted to: EMAIL.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.835--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class NewCreateCache] is being defaulted to: NewCreateCache.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.836--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [error_message] is being defaulted to: ERROR_MESSAGE.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.836--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [aggregator] is being defaulted to: AGGREGATOR.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.836--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [error_code] is being defaulted to: ERROR_CODE.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.837--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The column name for element [error_flag] is being defaulted to: ERROR_FLAG.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.837--ServerSession(648680157)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class companyMaster] is being defaulted to: companyMaster.
[EL Config]: metadata: 2017-08-05 12:50:10.838--ServerSession(648680157
```

Comment: I am using JPA, EclipsLink is a part of JPA . so I tagged this question for JPA users also

Comment: You tagged it as Hibernate. You're not using Hibernate.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, Have you resolved it ?

Comment: @Rahulkhanvani in  persistence.xml file use <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF" />
for more info visit this 
 https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_logging_level.htm